# Unable to disable SIP on BigSur

Tags: macos

I'm trying to disable System Integrity protection on BigSur 11.1 OS which is a VM on Fusion 11.x. I'm trying to boot machine in recovery mode, however VM is unable to get `cmd + R` keys and  booting ends up with normal booting.

I have Catalina 10.15.7 installed and SIP is disabled in it, in case I upgrade to BigSur, will SIP still be disabled?

If not, any other way to disable the SIP on BigSur?

Comment: Big Sur has additional security features beyond SIP that continue to protect the OS. What are you trying to do with SIP disabled? I can't see how having SIP disabled would help you to boot to recovery. There are other ways of setting the boot mode before restart.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I updated my Mac from **macOS Catalina (10.15.5) to Big Sur  Beta 1**, SIP was enabled again.
But I **can't ensure you that it will work**.

I found [this](https://babodee.wordpress.com/2018/10/10/booting-into-macos-recovery-in-vmware-fusion-10/) on Google :

1. 'Power on to firmware' from the Virtual Machine menu
2. Select 'Enter Setup'
3. Boot from the file
4. Arrow down to Recovery HD
5. Hit `Enter`until you can pick `boot.efi`
6. Select `boot.efi`
7. Hit `Enter` and you should now be able to disable SIP.

Comment: There is no `boot.efi` in the `Recovery HD` for Big Sur.

Comment: There is no 'boot.efi'. there are many files named 'bootbase.efi.xxxxx.yyyy' and 'boot.efi.xxxxxx.yyyy' where 'xxxxxx' and 'yyyy' are hexadecimal combination.

Comment: I should add the following. If you can [create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372), then you could use tama's answer. I use VirtualBox and was able to use this method to disable SIP. Also, if you have an ISO installer file of El Capitan or newer macOS, then you could boot the ISO from the virtual optical drive.